# Suppress empty result from 'many' in 'seq(p, many(p))' construct with parser combinators

Tags: functional-programming, postscript, parser-combinators

I'm trying to build parser combinators following Hutton and Meijer, "Monadic Parser Combinators". My implementation is in PostScript, but I think my issue is general to combinator parsers and not my specific implementation.

As a small exercise, I'm using the parsers to recognize regular expressions.

```
(pc9.ps)run

/Dot         (.) char         def
/Meta        (*+?) anyof      def
/Character   (*+?.|()) noneof def

/Atom        //Dot
             //Character  plus  def
/Factor      //Atom  //Meta maybe  seq   def
/Term        //Factor  //Factor many  seq  def
/Expression  //Term  (|) char //Term xthen  many  seq  def

/regex { string-input //Expression exec ps } def

(abc|def|ghi) regex 

quit
```

It's working, but the output has lots of `[]` empty arrays that really get in the way when I try to `bind` handlers to process the values.

```
$ gsnd -q -dNOSAFER pc9re2.ps
stack:
[[[[[97 []] [[98 []] [[99 []] []]]] [[[100 []] [[101 []] [[102 []]
[]]]] [[[103 []] [[104 []] [[105 []] []]]] []]]] null]]
```

These are happening whenever a `seq` sequencing combinator accepts the result from `maybe` or `many` (which uses `maybe`) that had zero occurrences.

What is the normal way of excluding this extra noise in the output with Parser Combinators?

[github repo](https://github.com/luser-dr00g/pcomb/tree/42c9065012d8a508208164c1b5c8778bec5fdadb)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sigh. It's seems I can just implement around it. I added special code in `seq` to detect an empty right-hand-side and just discard it. On to other problems...

*Edit:* I encountered the same problem again in version 11 (and a half). Now I've got a better solution IMO:

https://groups.google.com/g/comp.lang.functional/c/MbJxrJSk8Mw/m/MoT3Dr0IAwAJ

> Ugh. I think it wasn't even an X/Y problem. It was a "doctor it hurts
> when I move my arm like this; ... so don't move your arm like that"
> problem.
>
> I want the "result" part of the "reply" structure (using new terms
> following usage from the Parsec document) to be any of the /usual/
> PostScript types: integer, real, string, boolean, array, dictionary.
>
> But I also need some way to arbitrarily combine or concatenate two
> objects regardless of type. My `then` (aka `seq`) combinator needs to
> do this. So I made a hack-y function that does the combining. If it
> has two arrays, it composes the contents into a longer array. If it
> has one array and some other object it extends the array by one and
> stuffs  the object in the front or back as appropriate. If it has two
> non-array objects it makes a new 2-element array to contain them.
>
> So, instead of building `xthen` and `thenx` off of `then` and needing
> to cons, car, and cdr the stuff, I can write all 3 of these as a more
> general parameterized function.
>
> ```
> sequence{ p q u }{
>   { /p exec +is-ok {
>       next x-xs force /q exec +is-ok {
>         next x-xs 3 1 roll /u exec exch consok
>       }{
>         x-xs 3 2 roll ( after ) exch cons exch cons cons
>       } ifelse
>     } if } ll }  @func
> then { {append} sequence }
> xthen { {exch pop} sequence }
> thenx { {pop} sequence }
>
> append { 1 index zero eq { exch pop }{
>                   dup zero eq { pop }{
>          1 index type /arraytype eq {
>              dup type /arraytype eq { compose }{ one compose } ifelse
>          }{ dup type /arraytype eq { curry }{ cons } ifelse } ifelse } ifelse } ifelse }
> ```
>
> (`@func` is my own non-standard extension to PostScript that takes a
> procedure body and list of parameters and wraps the procedure with
> code that defines the arguments in a local dictionary. `ll` is my
> hack-y PostScript way of making lambdas with hard-patched parameters,
> it's short for `load all literals.`)

The code also treats *executable arrays* (ie. PostScript procedures) as
a non-array for the purpose of combining sequences of results. This allows
the parser to be used as a syntax-directed compiler producing procedures
as output.